# Refactor this nested IF function that is wrapped in a try/catch

Tags: refactoring

I have a messy function that needs refactoring, it has too many nested IF's and it makes me nervous just to look at it!

**Please ignore what the functions are doing, I'm more concerned with the structure/flow and how it can be refactored so it has less nested IF statements**

The basic flow is as follows:

```
public static void HandleUploadedFile(string filename)
{

      try
      {
        if(IsValidFileFormat(filename)
        {

            int folderID = GetFolderIDFromFilename(filename);

            if(folderID > 0)
            {

                if(HasNoViruses(filename)
                {

                    if(VerifyFileSize(filename)
                    {

                        // file is OK
                        MoveToSafeFolder(filename);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DeleteFile(filename);
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    DeleteFile(filename);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                DeleteFile(filename);
            }



        }
        else
        {
            DeleteFile(filename);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }
      finally
      {
        // do some things
      }


}
```

Answer (score 10):

I would be tempted to go as far as:

```
    private static bool CanMoveToSafeFolder(string filename)
    {
        return IsValidFileFormat(filename)
            && GetFolderIDFromFilename(filename) > 0
            && HasNoViruses(filename)
            && VerifyFileSize(filename);
    }

    public static void HandleUploadedFile(string filename)
    {

        try
        {

            if (CanMoveToSafeFolder(filename))
            {
                // file is OK
                MoveToSafeFolder(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                DeleteFile(filename);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            // do some things
        }

    }
```

Comment: In the original code, if IsValidFileFormat was false, the file got deleted.  This isn't equivalent.

Comment: Sorry - that's what I get for copying and pasting without reading properly. I've fixed it.

Comment: this answer is technically correct and better than what the poster had, but it's still not really designed with good object orient principals.

Comment: I think the original question was more about structuring nested conditions than actually deciding if an uploaded file can be moved to a safe folder. My point is that moving the checks to another method preserves the logic while improving the readability.

Answer (score 3):

The following is equivalent to your original code.

```
public static void HandleUploadedFile(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        if( IsValidFileFormat(filename) && 
            (GetFolderIDFromFilename(filename) > 0) && 
            HasNoViruses(filename) &&
            VerifyFileSize(filename) )
        {
              MoveToSafeFolder(filename);
        }
        else
        {
              DeleteFile(filename);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do some things
    }
    finally
    {
        // do some cleanup
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the error I made -- just missed the last else because it didn't fit on my screen -- but there's no point in me rewriting mine to make it look like yours.

Comment: This is what I would do. I don't think I would split that bit out into another function as another answerer did, unless I expected to use that logic again.

Answer (score 0):

This honors the original conditions under which the file is deleted and is cleaner and more compact.  My first answer set folderId, but I then realized it isn't used.

```
public static void HandleUploadedFile(string filename) {
    try {
        if(IsValidFileFormat(filename) 
        && GetFolderIDFromFilename(filename)>0 
        && HasNoViruses(filename) 
        && VerifyFileSize(filename)) {
            MoveToSafeFolder(filename);                                 // file is OK
            }
        else {
            DeleteFile(filename);
            }
        }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // HANDLE THE EXCEPTION; AT LEAST LOG IT!
        }
    finally {
        // do some things
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to refactor your case (sorry for the java style):

I will create a class `UploadedFileChecker`implemented as follow:

```
private class UploadedFileChecker {
    String fileName;

    UploadedFileChecker(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void check() throws BadUploadedFileException {
        checkNameFormat();
        checkFolderId();
        scanVirus();
        checkFileSize();
    }

    private void checkFolderId() {
        // throw BadUploadedFileException if not passed.
    }

    private void checkNameFormat() {
        // throw BadUploadedFileException if not passed.
    }

    private void scanVirus() {
        // throw BadUploadedFileException if not passed.
    }

    private void checkFileSize() {
        // throw BadUploadedFileException if not passed.
    }
}
```

With the exception

```
public class BadUploadedFileException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

And the refactored handleUploadedFile will become:

```
public static void handleUploadedFile(string filename) {

   try {
        checkFile(fileName);
    } catch (BadUploadedFileException ex) {
        deleteFile(fileName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

   } finally {

   }
}

private static void checkFile(String fileName) {
    new UploadedFileChecker(fileName).check();
}

private static void deleteFile(String fileName) {

}
```